"Austausch" als "Diskussion"
In der Schweiz wird das Wort "Austausch" benutzt, um regelmässige berufliche Termine zu benennen. Zum Beispiel, habe ich wöchentlich in meiner Agenda einen Termin "[Abteilung XX]-Austausch". Aber jemand hat mir auf Wiktionary.de erwähnt (https://de.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Austausch&diff=10029468&oldid=10029406), dass diese Benutzung von "Austausch" als eine "Diskussion" einfach nicht existiert, und ja, ich finde in Duden diese Bedeutung explizit nicht.
Also, dürfen wir "Austausch" als Synonym zu "Besprechung" benutzen, oder ist das ein Fehler?

Austausch = Disussion ist sicher keine 1:1 Entsprechung.
Bei einem Austausch kann es sicher auch zu Diskussionen kommen, hier können aber auch allgemeine Themen verkündet oder der aktuelle Flurfunk besprochen werden. Austausch ist ein Überbegriff

Danke für das Kommentar @jmk !

DWDS gibt als Bedeutung für Diskussion als erstes Meinungsaustausch an.
Abgesehen davon, dass man benutzen darf, was man will, solange alle Betroffenen die Bedeutung verstehen, halte ich die Aussage, die Bedeutung Diskussion würde für das Wort Austausch nicht existieren, für vollkommen abwegig.

Danke für deine Erklärung @Olafant !

Ich bin Schweizer, und wenn ich einen Termin mit dem Namen "Austausch" im Kalender habe, dann verstehe ich das als Treffen einer Gruppe, wo jeder erzählt was der Stand ist von seinen Aufgaben. Hierbei kommt es generell nicht zur Diskussion, da lediglich Fakten dargelegt werden. (Es kann aber schon einmal vorkommen, dass jemand nicht "einverstanden" ist mit dem was erzählt wird, z.B. wenn jemand eine Deadline verpasst und man dann diskutieren muss wie es weitergeht.)
Der Sinn eines Austauschs ist es also, dass alle Beteiligten auf dem neusten Stand der Anderen sind.

Hoi @kscherrer, vielen Dank für deine Antwort, und schöne!

Als Feststehender Begriff für eine wiederkehrende Veranstaltung wäre es mir jetzt nicht bekannt. Da sind "[...]-treffen" oder meeting vermutlich geläufiger, der Austausch wird dabei impliziert.
Allerdings gibt es die Worte "Gedankenaustausch", "Meinungsaustausch" und "im Austausch miteinander stehen" und das Konzept von Austausch als Diskussion, miteinander und treffen ist durchaus bekannt.
https://www.stackfield.com/de/blog/zusammenarbeit-im-team-verbessern-208

Transparenter Informationsfluss: Sind die Teammitglieder gut miteinander im Austausch, lassen sich lästige Missverständnisse oder unnötige Doppelarbeit vermeiden.


Durch den interdisziplinären Austausch lernen die Mitarbeitenden voneinander.


Fördert Innovation: Ein intensiver Austausch (z. B. Brainstorming) unter den Teammitgliedern bringt oft neue Ideen und Lösungen zu Tage.

Also je nach Kontext ist es vermutlich schon klar was gemeint ist, aber im schlimmsten Fall liest man es ohne Kontext halt als Austausch der Abteilung also als eine Art Schichtwechsel.

Danke für die Abklärung @haxor789 !
